# UML схема последовательности, с чем ее едят?

Tags: uml

Приветствую! Столкнулся с заданием, ничего подобного раньше не делал. Нужно построить UML схему последовательности для регистрации в веб системе. Просьба посмотреть на мою схему и сказать, адекватная ли она вообще? Так как,повторюсь, раньше никогда не сталкивался, не могу оценить свою работу. Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Register и Registered users - это объекты в системе?

Comment: Register - это класс в котором проводится проверка данных, а Registered users хранит инфу про зарегестрированных пользователей